# curl sending null objects in data field when parsing through a bash variable

Tags: bash, curl

I am trying to send the list of IPs as data in curl.

Curl adds null objects in data field when I try to parse the data through a bash variable (Here, $ips). It works fine without using the variable, however, I need to use that since the number of IPs is not constant. Below is exact command/syntax used with output:

```
mabosvgori-m2:Qualys_Auth_Scan vgori$ ips=`cat PRIVATE_IPs`
mabosvgori-m2:Qualys_Auth_Scan vgori$ echo "$ips"
["XX.XX.XX.XX", "YY.YY.YY.YY", "ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ",....]
mabosvgori-m2:Qualys_Auth_Scan vgori$ curl -v -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X "POST" -d "$ips" "https://aa.bb.info/TEST/APP/Scan" --trace-ascii /dev/stdout
Warning: --trace-ascii overrides an earlier trace/verbose option
== Info:   Trying XX.YY.ZZ.AA...
== Info: Connected to aa.bb.info (XX.YY.ZZ.AA) port 443 (#0)
== Info: TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
== Info: Server certificate: *.bb.info
== Info: Server certificate: DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
== Info: Server certificate: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
=> Send header, 178 bytes (0xb2)
0000: POST /TEST/APP/Scan HTTP/1.1
0027: Host: aa.bb.info
003f: User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
0058: Accept: */*
0065: Content-Type:application/json
0084: Content-Length: 6907
009a: Expect: 100-continue
00b0: 
<= Recv header, 23 bytes (0x17)
0000: HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
=> Send data, 6907 bytes (0x1afb)
0000: ["XX.XX.XX.XX", "YY.YY.YY.YY", "ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ",....]
== Info: We are completely uploaded and fine
<= Recv header, 36 bytes (0x24)
0000: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
<= Recv header, 46 bytes (0x2e)
0000: Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2016 19:05:48 GMT
<= Recv header, 27 bytes (0x1b)
0000: Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
<= Recv header, 23 bytes (0x17)
0000: Vary: Accept-Encoding
<= Recv header, 69 bytes (0x45)
0000: X-Trace: 1B686AF995169D1B189FCEB49C21AA676B73E2E45F3598FBDC3699E
0040: EB3
<= Recv header, 28 bytes (0x1c)
0000: transfer-encoding: chunked
<= Recv header, 24 bytes (0x18)
0000: Connection: keep-alive
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
<= Recv data, 6163 bytes (0x1813)
0000: 180b
0006: {.  "error" : "Cannot invoke method getPlatformId() on null obje
0046: ct",.  "stacktrace" : "org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.in
0086: vokeMethod(NullObject.java:88)\norg.codehaus.groovy.runtime.call
00c6: site.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)\norg.code
0106: haus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteA
0146: rray.java:45)\norg.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite
0186: .call(NullCallSite.java:32)\norg.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsit
01c6: e.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45......
```

> I cannot use --data-urlencode or any other encoding option as the server script doesn't support those.

Answer (score 0):

I really thought it was `curl` but I figured its `cat` which was the culprit here.

Using `cat PRIVATE_IPs | tr -dc '[:digit:],."[]'` resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong again. I finally figured it's the null-bytes in IP address themselves which give the issue. That is, if the IP address contains something like `XX.YY.100.ZZ` it will throw this error.